# Wicket ListView: do not output "container" tag

Tags: java, html, wicket, wicket-6

I'm trying to create a `ListView` or a `Repeater` in `Wicket 6` in order to output a list of items like this:

```
<div class="header">My first header</div>
<div class="content">My first content</div>

<div class="header">My second header</div>
<div class="content">My second content</div>

<div class="header">My third header</div>
<div class="content">My third content</div>

...
```

I tried to use a ListView like this:

```
<div wicket:id="listViewItems">
    <div class="header" wicket:id="header"></div>
    <div class="content" wicket:id="content"></div>
</div>
```

and populate it like this:

```
add(new ListView<MyItem>("listViewItems", myListOfItems) {
        @Override
        protected void populateItem(ListItem<MyItem> item) {
            item.add(new Label("header", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "header")));
            item.add(new Label("content", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "content")));
        }           
   });
```

The output I get is:

```
<div>
    <div class="header">My first header</div>
    <div class="content">My first content</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="header">My second header</div>
    <div class="content">My second content</div>
</div>

<div>
    <div class="header">My third header</div>
    <div class="content">My third content</div>
</div>
```

The problem is this: **I don't want those outer divs that wrap every header/content couple**. I want the list to be "flat" like in the example I made above.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can give `setRenderBodyOnly(true)` for `ListView` or use `wicket:container` in HTML instead of `div`

like below

```
<wicket:container wicket:id="listViewItems">
    <div class="header" wicket:id="header"></div>
    <div class="content" wicket:id="content"></div>
</wicket:container>
```

Comment: You'd have to call setRenderBodyOnly(true) on the ListView's items though, you can override newItem() for that.